# Find, wrap and replace occurrences in a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I Have a list of prefixes:
`foo.bar.`
`abc.`

Now consider this string:

```
{\n\"a\":foo.bar.user.email,\n\"b\":\"abc.name\"\n}
```

How do I find every occurrence of substrings that start with one of my prefixes and then wrap it with `${}` and remove quotes (if present)?

For example in the above string the desired output should be:

```
{\n\"a\":${foo.bar.user.email},\n\"b\":${abc.name}\n}
```

another example:

```
The quick abc.brown, fox jumps over the foo.bar.lazy\n"abc.dog"\n
```

desired output:

```
The quick ${abc.brown}, fox jumps over the ${foo.bar.lazy}\n${abc.dog}\n
```

Comment: A basic regular expression can make the match and replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a very laxed and simplified sense, you could use this as a starting point

`"?(?<![a-z])((?:foo\.bar|abc)(?:\.[a-z]*)+)"?`

Replace `${$1}`

https://regex101.com/r/eoWkWA/1

```
"?
(?<! [a-z] )
(                             # (1 start)
  (?: foo \. bar | abc )
  (?: \. [a-z]* )+
)                             # (1 end)
"?
```